# How to send string[] to the spring controller?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, http-request-parameters

I have the following JQuery code which sends some request parameters to my Spring MVC controller. For some parameters I should get multiple values.

```
 $('#tb-email').click(function(event) {
     var base, data, formats, recipients, reportSource, reportSourceType;
     if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass('disabled')) {
         return false;
     }
     base = "<base href=\"" + window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.DashboardGlobals.baseUrl + "\">";
     data = $('html').clone().find('script').remove().end().find('nav').remove().end().find('#dashboardCanvas').removeClass('dashboardCanvas').end().find('head').prepend(base).end().html();
     data = encodeURIComponent(Base64.encode('<html>' + data + '</html>'));
     $.post(window.DashboardGlobals.sendMail, {
         formats: ['png', 'pdf'],
         recipients: ['abc@xyz.com', 'xyz@abc.com'],
         reportSource: data, //Base64 data
         reportSourceType: 'adhoc',
         reportName: 'DataQualityApp'
     });
     event.preventDefault();
 });
```

When the `tb-email` is clicked, request is submitted to some controller which is saved in the `DashboardGlobals` variable.

At the server side I have written the following Java code to get the multiple values for the parameters formats and recipients.

```
public @ResponseBody String process(@RequestParam("formats") String[] formats, @RequestParam("recipients") String[] recipients, @RequestParam("reportSource") String reportSource, @RequestParam("reportSourceType") String reportSourceType, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...Some Processing....
    return null;
}
```

I checked the `formats` and `recipients` length which is 1.

I even tried to get the values using

```
String[] formats = request.getParameterValues("formats");
String[] recipients = request.getParameterValues("recipients");
```

Still I am getting single values in the array. The length is still one?

What is going wrong?

Comment: have you tried checking the value of `formats` if it contains an array.

Comment: use data: `JSON.stringify(yourarray)`  then in controller get using `JSONArray` not `String[]`.

Comment: @Kerppag It consists of single value

Comment: can you post the output when you sysout request.getParamterValues("formats");

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, spring controller can take csv as array or list:

```
$.post(window.DashboardGlobals.sendMail, {
     formats: ['png', 'pdf'].join(","),//<-- create csv string
     recipients: ['abc@xyz.com', 'xyz@abc.com'].join(","),//<-- create csv string
     ...
});
```

***OR***

```
$.post(window.DashboardGlobals.sendMail, {
     formats: 'png,pdf',
     recipients: 'abc@xyz.com,xyz@abc.com',
     ...
});
```